# Managing different git repository for an application

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a project and a git repository for that in BitBucket. For now, all the development and production codes are pushed to the same repo, which I think is pretty bad flow. I would like to setup separate repository for development and production.

I was wondering, what would be the best way to do that? Could you please elaborate the way I should do it or the tools I will be needing to solve this.

Comment: What makes you think you need another repository and not branch? Is there any particular reason?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a basic knowledge of git, I would recommended to you read about branches. You don't need to create another repo for dev/prod code. Use just another branch for it and then in every moment you could merge dev branch to prod [git branches](https://backlogtool.com/git-tutorial/en/stepup/stepup1_1.html)  :)

Answer (score 3):

As chebad said you should try to read about branches. Each branch normally will have a different enviroment. It will depend on your git workflow 
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Great visual tool: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Great free book/blog: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1